# Can't access programs on Ubuntu 16.04 USB install

Tags: usb

Most of the time a reboot is necessary for the system to function properly on the laptop I installed it on originally.
But doesn't seem to work while on any different pc as the programs are not accessible and usb seems to be in read only mode when that happens.

Comment: Are you booting from a USB, and trying to run programs from that live USB?

Comment: No, I have installed on a usb, not the live CD but the OS itself. And got it running normally and used it for a couple of days, but at some reboots (or every time I plug into a different pc) I get this issue.

Comment: K - if the USB is popping into RO mode, perhaps you should run fsck on the device

Comment: I'll try that and give feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is bad sectors on the drive
Migrating the ubuntu install into a different drive fixed the issue